# How do I use findAndModify()? to push an array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My userSchema is:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('users', {
    userName: String,
    messages: Array 
});
```

Messages will be:

```
messages: [{msg: "foo", time: new Date()},{msg: "Bar", time: new Date()}]
```

I want to be able to create a new record if there is no match userName, or if it is found, array.push the `msg` and `time` into the DB.

```
userSchema.findAndModify({
    query:{userName: "Test"},
    update:{$push: {messages: {msg: "foo", time: new Date()}}},
});
```

I'm assuming this is correct, how would I add a new user if there is no found `userName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your above query is true,

Your above query should have `upsert:true`

Like

`userSchema.findAndModify({
    query:{userName: "Test"},
    update:{$push: {messages: {msg: "foo", time: new Date()}}},
    new: true,

    upsert : true
});`

Here `new` indicates returning the updated or inserted object.
`upsert` indicates inserting a new record or updating a record depending on the record existence criteria.

Now when you push first message, if the username does not exists, then it will automatically be inserted.

Otherwise if you want to insert other attributes of user,
you should use `update: { $set:` command.

Hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: How do I do this with mongoose? "findOneAndUpdate"

Comment: mongoose give two options ``findOneAndUpdate`` and ``findByIdAndUpdate`` . They internally call ``findAndModify``. In your case it will be ``findOneAndUpdate``

Comment: Thank you, I literally had 100 lines of code just to do this before I found out about findAndModify. My code is SOO clean now.